# How do I turn off spoken notifications?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, settings

Can't figure out how to change the settings on my Samsung Galaxy S phone to actually have a ringtone when receiving a call.

When receiving a call a voice says "call from 123-456-7890" or "call from Fred". I know how to set the ringtone which has been set..but I don't know how to take the voice off.

So how do I turn off these spoken notifications and get back the ringtone I've set?

Comment: sounds like you have some 3rd party application that "announces" the calls.

Comment: Also see if there's something in the Accessibility Settings that's rendering this functionality.

Answer (score 8):

On my Droid 2 it's under Settings > Call Settings > Caller ID Readout...then you can set Ring Only, Caller ID then Ring, or Caller ID Repeat.  I realize you have a different phone, but I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have Caller ID Readout on my Droid (2.2.1).    Would love to have that option when using a headset.

Comment: All I get is the number on my earpiece.  But my wife, also using a Droid 2, gets the Caller ID.  The only difference I can find is that she got an LG earpiece and I got a Jawbone.

Answer (score 6):

For Galaxy S2 go to `Settings -> Language and Input -> Text-to-speech output` and turn off `Driving Mode`. This should turn off both call and messaging readout.

Comment: This is in the same place on a Galaxy S with Gingerbread

Comment: This finally told me where this setting was, seems to be in different places in different phones!

Answer (score 5):

In Epic 4G (imagine same for other Galaxy S handsets):

Settings -> Text-To-Speech -> Speak incoming CallerID

Answer (score 1):

Go into `Settings->Accessibility` and uncheck "Talk back".

Answer (score 1):

For Galaxy S2, in Settings, Voice input and output, Text-to-speech settings, turn off Driving mode, this should turn off both call and messaging readout.

Actually, you have to go into the driving mode settings and disable the option for incoming call read out.  I disabled all of the read out messages for new email etc.  I don't want my phone talking to me ever! Turning off driving mode did not work on my new Galaxy s2.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I had the same problem.

Go into `Settings`, then click `Voice input and output` Next, click `Text-to-speech settings`, from there you should see something called `Driving Mode`. If its got a tick next to it, you've found your problem. Untick driving mode and the voice will stop reading out the number.

I accidentally clicked that button a while back, and have spent the past week trying to work out how to put it back.

Answer (score 1):

This applies to the AT&T SGS2 (SGHi777). My problem started when I ran the "Voice Command" app. I started the driving mode, but even after I turned it off, it would still read the CID in my ear. After reading all the answers here and trying everything, I still had the problem. I finally tried -Settings->Voice input and output->Text-to-speech settings->Check "Always use my settings". Finally I have peace. Thank you everyone who helped steer me in the right direction.